# convert api response into view in nodejs

Tags: node.js

How do I convert response to usable {app_sale_price.value} in view ?

```
    function(error, response) {
    if (!error) {
      res.send(response['resp_result']['result']['products']['product'][1]);
      const jsonResponse = await response.json();
      return JSON.stringify(jsonResponse);
      const arrayOfLists = jsonResponse.records.map(
        record => {app_sale_price.value}
        )
    return arrayOfLists;
    } else {
      res.send(error);
    }
  })
```

Comment: You have a variable definition after a `return` statement that will never run, additionally `app_sale_price` is not defnied anywhere?